# Solving the rejected push of only-a-file push

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

how solving the rejected push of only-a-file push to replace its remote counterpart on github ?
Try this https://happygitwithr.com/push-rejected.html
without any success

e.g. message

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/abdulbadii/MatrixMultiplier'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

Comment: "hint: Updates were rejected _because the remote contains work that you do not have locally_. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to _first integrate the remote changes_." "hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in _'git push --help'_ for details"

Comment: PS pushes are always about _commits_ and _never_ about file(s).

Answer (score 0):

it seems like someone else working on the same git branch,
so just stash your modifications using
`git stash`

and then run  `git pull origin  branch_name` 
and then to get your changes , run  `git stash pop`

after that push your code